# URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string

Tags: magento2, indexer, cronjobs

I'm struggling with an error that is thrown in the debug.log. The problem is that multiple indexers are not updated allthough the cronjobs are running.

Re-indexing by CLI is working properly on all indexers but that cannot be the solution.

The debug.log

```
[2020-09-17 05:25:12] main.ERROR: Cron Job indexer_reindex_all_invalid has an error: URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string. Statistics: {"sum":0,"count":1,"realmem":0,"emalloc":0,"realmem_start":146800640,"emalloc_start":143814352} [] []
[2020-09-17 05:25:12] main.CRITICAL: URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string {"exception":"[object] (Laminas\\Uri\\Exception\\InvalidUriException(code: 0): URI is not valid and cannot be converted into a string at /PATH/web/vendor/laminas/laminas-uri/src/Uri.php:363)"} []
```

I took a look at the specified line but it's just the function that throws the exception. How can i find the 'url' that is causing the problem?

Config:

- Magento 2.3.5.-p1
- PHP 7.3-Stable

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will be thrown if you for example have redirect result set up, and the URL for it is not set correctly.

For example:

```
$redirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
$redirect->setUrl('a/b/c'); // this is missing = PROBLEM
return $redirect;
```